# Find time that is logged into other member's tasks

Tags: jira

When I'm helping another team member with his task I log my time into his task. At the end of the month I want to calculate how much time I have spent on other's tasks.

How can I find this time that is logged into other member's tasks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably best to use a JIRA app for this. However, you can get a list of all these issues using "Search for issues". Switch to the "Advanced" search and use a query like this:

```
assignee != currentUser() AND worklogAuthor = currentUser() AND worklogDate > startOfMonth() ORDER BY key ASC
```

You can of course replace "startOfMonth()" with an actual date and optionally add a upper limit for the worklogDate.

If you add "Time Spent" to the columns of the search results, you can see the time you spent on each of these issues.

Export the resulting list to CSV and import in Excel. You can then sum the values in the "Time Spent" column. The values in this column are in seconds.